# VSCode failed to open terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I am trying to open a terminal in VS Code but I got this message:

The terminal process command "c:\windows\system32' failed to launch (exit code:2)

Comment: how did you try to open a terminal window?

Comment: In Visual Studio Code when i try to open a new terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try this in VS Code:

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings
```

Then navigate to `Features -> Terminal`

Scrolling down, you should hopefully see `"Integrated > Automation Shell:Windows"` and just below it `"Edit in settings.json"`. Clicking on that will open the json file and I adjusted mine (2nd line from the bottom) to:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

That worked for me with the exit code I was getting

Answer (score -2):

Open VScode and go to the "View" menu. Click on the View menu item and then click on "Terminal". A terminal window should now open.

Comment: Yes I know This, but I when I open the terminal this way I get the error code.
The terminal process command "c:\windows\system32' failed to launch (exit code:2)